# Burgers PDE with piecewise constant initial condition

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

Let's deal with this Burgers PDE:

[image]

You can see the characteristic curves below:

[image]

1. **I believe the breaking time is $\boldsymbol{t_b=0}$**, because it is the $\inf$ of $t$-coordinates of the intersection points of characteristics curves. Am I right?
2. **How can I find the weak solution? How can I find the discontinuity line?** At $t=0$ we have $x=\alpha$ and $x=\beta$ at the intersection points.

*Thanks, in advance!*