# Solving PDE $u_t+f(u)u_x=0$ using its physical interpretation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

Let's be this PDE:

$\begin{cases}u_t+f(u)u_x=0\\
u(x,0)=\varphi(x) \end{cases}$

and $f\in 1-1$.

- **I have these thoughts:**

We can imagine $x'x$ having sticky particles. As we know $\frac{dx}{dt}=f(u)$. So $f(u)$ is the velocity of the particle at the position $x$ at the time $t$. Also, at the time characteristics intersect we have inelastic collision.

So, if we find the velocity of each particle at position $x$ at time $t$ (let's be $v(x,t)$, the weak solution of PDE will be $u=f^{-1}(v)$.

1. **Am I wrong?**
2. **If I 'm not wrong, I would like to find a reference for that.**

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Try [method of charcteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics) on wikipedia.

Comment: I know how to use characteristics. I have a problem with that (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/436604/burgers-pde-with-piecewise-constant-initial-condition) problem. So, I want to find another way to find weak solution.

Comment: The solution expressed on implicit form is 
$$u(x,t)=\varphi\left(x-\int_{\tau=0}^{\tau=t} f\Big(u(x,\tau)\Big)d\tau\right)$$
One cannot expect the explicit form $u(x,t)$ without knowing explicitly the functions $f$ and $\varphi$.